# How to read a large binary file using PHP and send few bytes each time through AJAX on clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to send some fixed length of data from a large binary file each time, when a user clicks a button.

I'm using PHP to read binary file and AJAX for receiving data. I tried the following way but same data is received every time when I click a button.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<button name="click" onclick="loadFile()">Click me!</button>
<div id="txt"></div>
<script>
        function loadFile() {
            console.log("ok here");
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "load_file.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**load_file.php**

```
<?php
$filename = "binary.DAT";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");

if (!$handle)
    die('file does not exist or cannot be opened');

$contents = substr(strtoupper(bin2hex(fread($handle, 200))),10*2,138*2);
$formatedContent = "<pre>" . implode(' ',str_split($contents, 2)) . "</pre>";
echo $formatedContent;
ob_flush();
flush();

fclose($handle);
?>
```

I'm expecting different data each time but each time I'm receiving same data. Any help on how to handle this case is highly appreciated.

Comment: Consider it like paging with records, you would pass in a start position each time (or blank for start of page) and use [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to position the read point in the file.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to send the file position each time when I click the button?

Comment: You will have to maintain the position somewhere, either in the client or in a session on the server.  As it doesn't look as though you are using sessions, I would have thought that the client could keep track of it (especially if you want a method of scrolling by the user)

Comment: Thank you @Nigel. I did exactly as you suggested and its working fine.

Comment: May be wort posting what you have done as an answer as it may help others in the future.